# How to get the web_path variable in php to use the same hostname as the request?

Tags: php, nginx, url, subnet

I'm setting up an [ampache](https://ampache.org/) server on my home network. I've got nginx, php, and ampache up and running, and everything seems fine except for access from outside my home network.

For example, let's say my router's public IP address is `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd`, and the server's LAN IP address is `192.168.xxx.yyy`. Outside my home network, if I do

```sh
curl -k https://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/login.php
```

all of the URLs in the resulting html reference `192.168.xxx.yyy`, which I obviously can't see from outside my home network. For example, look at [this code](https://github.com/ampache/ampache/blob/develop/public/templates/show_login_form.inc.php#L70):

```php
<form name="login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $web_path; ?>/login.php">
```

When I run curl as shown above, this gets rendered to

```html
<form name="login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://192.168.xxx.yyy/login.php">
```

I don't know much about php, but it seems like the `$web_path` part is being replaced by `https://192.168.xxx.yyy`, even though the URL I requested was `https://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd`.

My nginx virtual server config looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.xxx.yyy mydomain.no-ip.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
   listen      443 ssl default_server;
   server_name 192.168.xxx.yyy mydomain.no-ip.org;
}
```

Note that I have a no-ip dynamic DNS set up in case the public IP changes, but it doesn't matter if I use the domain name or the IP address, the result is the same. Since `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` isn't explicitly listed, the default server catches it, but all URLs in the html that gets returned still reference `192.168.xxx.yyy`.

In my ampache.cfg.php file, `http_host`, `http_port`, `web_path`, and `local_web_path` are all commented out. My understanding is that it should then use the host name that the client requested, which it isn't doing. If I set `http_host` and `http_port` explicitly, then it ***does*** use those to properly assemble URLs... however, for some reason, I am not allowed to access `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` from ***inside*** my network (I can't get any answers from my ISP about this). So, if I set those so that `http_host` is `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd`, it will always return html like

```html
<form name="login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/login.php">
```

If I'm outside my network, that's fine. If I'm at home, though, it will fail because it can't find aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd. So, I can force it to work for ***either*** internal or external access, but not both.

How should I resolve this? Is there a way to configure either ampache or nginx to build URLs based on the client's requested hostname?

Answer (score 0):

> My nginx virtual server config looks like:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name 192.168.xxx.yyy mydomain.no-ip.org;
>     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
> }
> ```

I think you should use `$host` variable here instead of `$server_name` one. This way you should receive a redirect to the same domain/IP that was requested. You can read about difference between those variables [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/706438/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-variables-host-http-host-and-server-na).

> In my ampache.cfg.php file, `http_host`, `http_port`, `web_path`, and `local_web_path` are all commented out. My understanding is that it should then use the host name that the client requested, which it isn't doing. If I set `http_host` and `http_port` explicitly, then it ***does*** use those to properly assemble URLs.

That information is available for PHP script through `$_SERVER` array elements. If you look into the default `fastcgi_params` file from the nginx distribution, you'll see the following:

> ```
> fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
> fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
> fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
> fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
>
> fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
> fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
> fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
> fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
> fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
> fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
>
> fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
>
> fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
> fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
> ```

In PHP script, used server name will be available to you via `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, used port via `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` and an URI (only relative part, i.e. `/login.php`) via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variables. I know nothing about ampache, but I think you can initialize those `http_host` and `http_port` variables in the `ampache.cfg.php` file like this:

```php
$http_host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$http_port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
```

> however, for some reason, I am not allowed to access aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd from inside my network

Is your server located behind the router with dynamic IP address?

Comment: If I put `http_host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` in my ampache.cfg.php, all URLs in the requested page have the literal string in there like `https://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]/browse.php`. 

I also tried with the leading `$`, like `$http_host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`, and that renders to `/browse.php`.

Regarding my server, yes, it is behind two routers. The one in my apartment, and the ISP's router that serves the whole building.

Comment: I downloaded ampache package and looked into the `ampache.cfg.php` file. It isn't a PHP file (the only PHP code line it contains is `<?php exit(); ?>` and after a quick look I see it is being parsed with [`parse_ini_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) PHP function inside the ampache code. I thought it is something similar to `config.inc.php` used by PhpMyAdmin, but unfortunately it isn't. While it is possible to patch the ampache configuration parser, it is definitely out of the scope for SO question. Sorry, your only chance is to ask ampache developers.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if this is a more general PHP issue or not. Thanks for your insight!